# How to use a ColorData gradient along with other PlotStyle options in a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, color, style

I want to use `ColorData` colors along with other manual options. Is that possible?

```
SeedRandom["ColorData problem aah help"]
data=RandomVariate[LogisticDistribution[.007,.01],{1200,2}];
dataClustered=FindClusters[data,4,DistanceFunction->EuclideanDistance];
ListPlot[dataClustered,PlotStyle->"PlumColors"]
```

[image]

But I would also like to add:

```
Directive[Opacity->.3,PointSize->.015]
```

I can't seem to add the `Directive` without losing the colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListPlot[dataClustered, 
 PlotStyle -> Thread[{ColorData["PlumColors"] /@ Rescale[Range@Length@dataClustered], 
  Opacity[.3], PointSize[.015]}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use:

```
PlotStyle -> (Directive[ColorData["PlumColors"]@#, Opacity[.3], 
     PointSize[.015]] & /@ Rescale[Range@Length@dataClustered])
```

Comment: Holy Plot that was quick... Thanks a lot, this does the job perfectly. I didn't realize ColorData was a function.

Comment: @EBassal, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.